# Clarification of an equality involving conditioning

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In this [wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLs_upper_limits#Origin), the first block equation claims that

$P(n_b \leq n^* | s+b)=P(n\leq n^* | b)$

Some context (also found in that linked section): $n_b$ follows $Pois(b)$ and $n_s$ independently follows $Pois(s)$, $b$ is known and $s$ is to be estimated, and only $n=n_b + n_s$ can be measured.

Wikipedia claims that the equality above is "easily seen", but I don't see it even after banging my head for an hour. How is that true?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the notation, but I don't get how $P(n\leq n^* \mid b)$ is even defined, as it would require averaging over $s$ but there is no probability distribution defined for $s$.

Comment: ^Same here actually - I am thinking that it's the wikipedia article that's the problem...